# extract only rows of a certain year, and count the most seen values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openrefine

I have a thousand of rows, in an excel sheet, which have dates where a patient got infected by a virus, and when she was healed. I also have in a third column, the virus id, which is like a foreign key, and points to another excel sheet, where the name of the virus is stored, along with the virusID. The date format looks like:

```
column A: patient infected date
2002-01-22 13:25:41 
column B: patient healed date
2002-01-24 10:35:21
```

What i try to do, is have the say 100 most usually seen viruses, that had infected and were healed in the same year, along their titles. (so infection and heal year, must be both say 2002)

something like (order by the number of occurrences, for year 2002):

```
virus1 | name of virus1 | number of occurrences 
virus2 | name of virus2 | number of occurrences
```

which excel formula should i use? or if someone could point me to an openrefine solution, even better. Have tried INDEX, MATCH, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually solve these kinds of problems in steps. First, make sure column A and column B are recognized as dates in Excel. Columns C is your virus ID. I'd make column D a year infected column with the formula =YEAR(A2) copied down to the rest of the column's cells. Column E should be Year Healed with =YEAR(B2) copied down to the rest of the column's cells. Column F would indicate whether the years match using =IF(E2=D2,1,0).

Finally, the meat of the work is done with the countifs function. Column G should have cells with the formula =COUNTIFS(C$2:C$541,C2,F$2:F$541,1). In my test example, I only had data through row 541. You'll have however many rows you have. Replace 541 with your last row number. To get the virus name, you'll use the virus ID to match the sheet with the virus ID and the virus name with something like this formula: =LOOKUP(C2,Viruses!A$2:A$4,Viruses!B$2:B$4) this assumes column A is the virus ID and column B is the virus name and they both have a one line header. In my sample, I only had 3 viruses.

Once you have these columns, sort by the count column (largest to smallest), then eliminate duplicates via Data, remove duplicates. Uncheck all the columns except the virus count columns and you should have what you need. If you need only data from a particular year, filter by one of the year columns before removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For OpenRefine I would do the following:

- Import the first Excel sheet as an OpenRefine project (called "project_1"). Let's assume this has columns:

  - infected_date
  - healed_date
  - virus_id
- Import the second Excel sheet as a separate OpenRefine project (called "project_2"). Let's assume this has columns

  - virus_id
  - virus_name
- In project_1 created, from the "virus_id" column use the 'add column based on this column option'

  - Use the GREL: `forEach(cell.cross("project_2","virus_id"),r,r.cells["virus_name"].value).join("|")`
  - call the new column "virus_name"
- In project_1

  - create a Text Facet on the virus_name column
  - create a "Custom text facet" on the infect_date column using the GREL: `(value.substring(0,4) == cells["healed_date"].value.substring(0,4)).toString()`
- If you select the 'true' value in the custom text facet, this will filter the projects to only rows where the infected & healed year are the same
- The Text facet on virus_name will give you the number of times each virus name appears in the set of rows

If you need to do a more precise 'date' comparison (e.g. find infected and healed dates that are within 365 days of each other) you could convert these values to dates in OpenRefine and use the GREL function `diff` to find the number of days (or months, years, hours etc.) between the two dates

Comment: how i could have these results from the text facets, on an excel sheet? i need in the first column to have the virus id, then its virus name, then the number of the occurrences?